# HPE Error code 4-3-3-1 (Do OEM initialization)

Tags: performance

Does anyone know what 'Do OEM initialization' entails? I've recently changed the CPU in a HPE ML110 G6 and now it's giving me 4-3-3-1 beeps, which correspond to an OEM initialization. I've looked around and can't find out what it actually wants me to do.

4-3-3-1 / E8h / Do OEM initialization

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put the old CPU back in. See what errors were logged.

Reseat and replace the new CPU.

Make sure you're using something that's actually compatible with the platform.

Comment: I've put the old CPU back in and now it's giving a 1-1-1-2 error code - this one isn't even listed. It's definitely not 1-1-1-3